# Changing <td> background-color when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for the functionality described in the topic. When the user hovers over an image (id="sie"), the background of an table cell (id="sein_img") should change. I tried using this code but I am not sure why it doesn't work. Help would be very much appreciated!

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("sein_img").onmouseover = function() {
                document.getElementById("sie").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
     </script> 

 <td id="sie" style="background-color: #f3f5f7;">&nbsp;sie</td>

 <img id="sein_img" src="images/stories/bullet_white.png" />
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afopp12s/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works perfectly fine, but only if you execute the `<script>` after the initialization of the affected HTML tags (in your case the `<div>` with the id `sein_img`). The element is not yet available, so the mouseover listener is not set to the element (the element you get with `document.getElementById()` is `undefined`.

So, to resolve your problem you can choose between those 2 options:

1. Move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page or at least after the last element you want to set a listener to.
2. Wait for the document to be ready before setting a listener to an element. You can e.g. do that with jQuery (`$(document).ready(function() { ... });`)

Answer (score 0):

Move the script to execute after rendering your html. I think it will also only work with a valid html table.

```
<table><tr><td id="sie" style="background-color: #f3f5f7;">&nbsp;sie</td></tr></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("sein_img").onmouseover = function() {
            document.getElementById("sie").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Is this....? Is this a table for layouting purposes? What year are we in..? 1999? And also non-breaking spaces...

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I'm just using the code from the question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this `<script />` after the html codes. You can check [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0JMl9yBUg3fSuvVRpBoW/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

1. You are accessing the elements before their creation.
2. You must put the **td** element in a **table** element otherwise its attributes will not be interpreted (in this case the id and style).

```html
<table>
    <td id="sie" style="background-color: #f3f5f7;">&nbsp;sie</td>
</table>
<img id="sein_img" src="images/stories/bullet_white.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("sein_img").onmouseover = function()   {
    document.getElementById("sie").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
</script>
```

If you just put the tag in the bottom of the body the code will not work.

```html
<td id="sie" style="background-color: #f3f5f7;">&nbsp;sie</td>
<img id="sein_img" src="images/stories/bullet_white.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("sein_img").onmouseover = function()   {
        document.getElementById("sie").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```